# first element to become the key each row

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a csv file that  contains 2  columns. Here is an  glimpse of how he looks:

```
A, john, robert, simon,peter
B, robert, isiah, elephant
C,james, bond, jack, chuck
```

What I want is to be able to make every element  of the first row a the key of the dictionary and make the rest  of the row the value. basically I want it to look this:

```
 A       B         C
john     robert    james
robert   isiah     bond
peter    elephant  jack
                   chuck
```

Comment: Where should `simon` be?

Comment: May be this? `{line.split(':')[0]:line.split(':')[1].split(',') for line in open('your_file.csv')}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pandas.read_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read) function:

Sample valid `input.csv` contents:

```
A: john, robert, simon, peter
B: robert, isiah, elephant, dave
C: james, bond, jack, chuck
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', header=None, engine='python', sep='[:,]',
                 skipinitialspace=True, index_col=0)
result = df.transpose()

print(result)
```

The output:

```
0        A          B       C
1     john     robert   james
2   robert      isiah    bond
3    simon   elephant    jack
4    peter       dave   chuck
```

---

Convert Dataframe to dictionary with [`pandas.DataFrame.to_dict()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html#pandas-dataframe-to-dict) function:

```
...
result = df.transpose().to_dict(orient='list')
print(result)
```

The output:

```
{'B': [' robert', ' isiah', ' elephant', ' dave'], 'A': [' john', ' robert', ' simon', ' peter'], 'C': [' james', ' bond', ' jack', ' chuck']}
```

Comment: this is   exactly what I want but my example was showing semi-colons  instead comma.the semi colons were just there  to  make the difference. I am having a problem with the separator.

Comment: I have  but  it gives me 1 rows instead of 3 or 4. They go to the right columns  but its like  I have one list for each  columns in which I have the 3 or 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
data_before = [
  ['A:john', 'robert', 'simon', 'peter'],
  ['B:robert', 'isiah', 'elephant'],
  ['C:james', 'bond', 'jack', 'chuck']
]

data_after = {row[0].split(':', 2)[0]: [row[0].split(':', 2)[1]]+row[1:] for row in data_before}
```